# Eslint (no-unused-vars) can't properly detect unused variable at Vue factory pattern

Tags: vue.js, eslint

Code Example:

[image: Edit cocky-sea-b2j1l]

Please see this minimum code below

```
import Vue from "vue";

const makeComponent = () => {
  let isMounted = false; // eslint yells

  return Vue.extend({
    name: "App",

    mounted() {
      isMounted = true;
    },
    destroyed() {
      isMounted = false;
    }
  });
};

export default makeComponent();
```

As you can see, I have properly use the `isMounted` value, but ESLint can't recognize it.

I have reload the editor, it didn't help.

[image]

This happens at codesandbox and my local editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are only assigning values to the variable, but never actually using it. The documentation for [no-unused-vars](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars) covers this nicely.

> A variable is not considered to be used if it is only ever declared (var foo = 5) or assigned to (foo = 7).

Here is an example of the variable being used in your example:

[image: Edit recursing-ishizaka-tujsx]

### Edit

I should probably include the correct way to go about going what you're trying to do:

[image: Edit quirky-shape-iznth]